# EWS communication error when downloading an email

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am reading continuous emails from the exchange server and processing their attachments. I have seen various examples of the same but I still get error

```
You must load or assign this property before you can read its value
```

My code is as below

```
ItemView itemView = new ItemView(NoEmailProcess);
itemView.OrderBy.Add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Ascending);
FindItemsResults<Item> searchResults = service.FindItems(folder.Id, itemView);
foreach (var item in searchResults)
{
  if (item is EmailMessage)
  {
    item.Load();
    try
    {
      // Process my email
    }
    catch
    {
        // error
    }
  }
}
```

The thing to note is that I dont get this error every time. I get it 10% of times and never during debugging

I was wondering should I use 'Bind' before the 'Load'?

```
EmailMessage.Bind
```

Not sure what the problem could be. Could someone please help with areas I should investigate?

Comment: What line is the error on? Have you tried using Bind to see if it is what you need?

Comment: The error is after Load but since the error is never during debug, I cant say the exact line, but since I have loaded the entire email, I should be able to read all properties?

Comment: No. Read the documentation for "Load". It doesn't load all the properties. You must say which properties you want and load them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

An exception with the message "*You must load or assign this property before you can read its value*" is thrown if you attempt to read a property which isn't present on `Item`.

The `Item`s returned by `service.FindItems` [contain only some properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2007/bb508824(v=exchg.80)). Though the property `ItemSchema.HasAttachments` is returned for an `Item`, the property `ItemSchema.Attachments` is missing. Thus you can only check if there are attachments present on an `Item`. But trying to read them at once will throw the shown exception.

Before you can read the property `ItemSchema.Attachments` you need to load it first,  You can do it by `ItemSchema.Bind` or `ItemSchema.Load`. Both calls result in a `GetItem` request.

Since a `GetItem` request returns the property `ItemSchema.Attachments` too (see the linked MS doc above) you are safe to read it.